# Cement board not ending on stud

Tags: cement, board

I am installing cement board in my tub surround and the cement board will not end on a stud on the left side of the wall. The studs are not 16” nor 24” on Center, it is more like 21” from the corner of the wall to the next stud to the right then the next stud is 16” away but that is way further out than I need to go. I am wondering if the use of butt sticks are an option or if I just end the cement Board on the stud that is 21” away from the wall and leave the rest the already existing moisture board.

Comment: Pictures might help, but why do you not just use more boards, cut properly to the stud?

Comment: Can you add a stud? Maybe even on the flat, so fastening would be simple...

Comment: I think your use of butt sticks or some horizontal supports 16” apart would supply the support needed

Comment: I’m only going up the wall 5 feet so I wouldn’t be able to add a stud I was thinking securing a couple 2x4s in between the studs to I have doming more stable than just butt sticks. I would much rather add a stud but I would have to tear the whole length of already existing moisture board to do that

Comment: 4 2x4s would be the right number. Or a short stud that bumps into a block you install.

Comment: This desperately needs a picture of the corner with a tape measure in it to clarify the issue.